# IoC using autofac and WCF IParameterInspector

Tags: wcf, autofac

I'm trying to use autofac in the following scenario:
A WCF service that, on every method call, receives connection details which it uses to open a DB connection.
(i.e. `public UserDTO GetUser(string dbUsername, string dbPassword, int userId)`.

Since opening a DB connection is common to all methods, I'd like to use an `IParameterInspector` to intercept every method call, extract the connection details, and initialize the connection.

My problems are-
1. I don't know if (and how) I can inject the necessary factory to my `IParameterInspector`
2. Once I've created my connection, I'm not sure as to how I can register it with my container so that it'll be available to all components for that request.

My `IParameterInspector` so far:

```
        public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {

            var userName = inputs[0] as Guid?;
            var password = inputs[1] as string;

            // How do I inject the ConnectionsFactory?
            var connection = ConnectionsFactory.CreateConnection(userName, password); 
           // How can I register my connection in the container, so that it'll be available to all dependencies created in this call?
            return null;
        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out-
My problem was that `IParameterInspector` was invoked *after* my service class was instanciated. So obviously that wasn't the place to do initializations.

Implementing a `IInstanceCreator` proved to be the right thing to do, since it's invoked *before* the creation of the service class, and is actually used to tell WCF how to create a service class.

I just created an autofac *Lifetime Scope*, and registered my DB Connection with it.