# Autofac WCF from IParameterInspector?

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac

I am using a `ParameterInspector` to do authentication for my WCF service. It has Autofac integrated with the `Autofac.WCF` package.

However, from this parameter inspector in the `BeforeCall` method, the `OperationContext` is unavailable.

How come?

The reason I need the `OperationContext` is to get a reference to my Autofac lifetime scope, like so:

`var lifetimeScope = OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Find<AutofacInstanceContext>().OperationLifetime`

Am I doing something wrong? Should I consider moving my authentication somewhere else? Or is there perhaps another way of injecting things via Autofac into the parameter inspector?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wcf. But you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050091/ioc-using-autofac-and-wcf-iparameterinspector

Answer (score 0):

This is 2018 (i.e. almost 5 years since original question) but I stumbled upon this question in an attempt to solve the very same problem by looking up stackoverflow solutions.

Following line got me thinking if I could do it differently.

> Or is there perhaps another way of injecting things via Autofac into
>   the parameter inspector?

I found it easier to get lifetime scope using AutofacHostFactory (must be new development since the question was asked. Currently as per autofac doc instance is set on AutofacHostFactory )

```
var accessResolver = AutofacHostFactory.Container.Resolve<IAccessResolver>();
```

I put above line in BeforeCall where access resolver contains authentication logic.